# allow more whitespace than just one space in HTML

Tags: html, whitespace

so I have a div that has tabs, line-breaks, and such. But for some reason, the div displays everything together...

here is a sample div:

```
<div>
    the(5 spaces after this)     re is a tab here      and now I break line
    twice now
    
            there are two tabs before me too
</div>
```

**why does this happen and how do I have it with the original white space?**

## [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yTEm3/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the text in a `<pre>` element or using CSS you can use `white-space: pre;`

```
div {
   white-space: pre; /* or pre-wrap if you want wrapping */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yTEm3/4/

Answer (score 1):

It happens because by HTML specifications, browsers [collapse white space](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#idx-white_space-2), i.e. any string of spaces, tabs, and line breaks is treated as equivalent to a single space characters. Described from another perspective, whitespace does separates words, and the amount of whitespace between words does not affect the spacing between the words in rendering.

Whenever this becomes a problem, you should consider what the content and structure really is. Perhaps you should use a `table` element, to present tabular data, or use CSS to tune spacing here and there. The use of `pre` element, or the CSS setting `white-space: pre`, should be regarded as last resort or as quick and dirty trick, since it effectively means escaping the HTML world and asking browsers to act as simplistic plain text renderers for the content.